# The sign-up process for alternative SE sites should be in the background

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, login, user-accounts

It's a bit of a hurdle to participate on a Stack Exchange site you've never used before. After reading something interesting, you have to stop and log in before being able to comment, vote, etc. Wouldn't it be better to be able to participate straight away without logging in?

I know with the current set-up, being automatically logged in to every site would mean that hundreds of sites would be displayed in your profile, but perhaps that can be changed so that a site would only display on your profile after the first activity is logged.

The way it is set up at the moment disincentivizes me from going through the sign up process. If my first vote is the difference between one click and three (with the screen changing pages), I'm less likely to contribute my first vote on that site, which in the grand scheme of things, means fewer votes on the network.

Comment: You should edit your question if you don't want to get it closed as a duplicate. I think that only the first paragraph is unique—otherwise, it does indeed read like a duplicate.

Comment: Just use the app (both iOS and android), that's exactly how they work. (Creating account silently when you try to perform action requiring it)

Comment: There are plenty of sites that have too many votes from exactly the usage you describe - people that come from HNQ and upvote trash because they have association bonus and are considered capable of judging content despite not having the damnedest clue about what is or isn't appropriate. If having to click twice and wait through a single screen to load makes that stop, it's a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with one aspect of this. If cookies allowed for it, it would be useful, in response to you doing something that requires membership, to be automatically prompted by the site to create a new (linked) account rather than having to go through the login process again. It would make for a slightly friendlier cross-site experience.

Comment: The user already is automatically _prompted_. I'm highlighting this subtle annoyance. What I'm proposing is that the new account automatically be created in the background.

Comment: @ahorn I've done this a few times. I get something that asks me to sign-up or login. I can then login with my network credentials—but I still have to provide those. What I'm saying is that after clicking **login**, if the fact that I'm already logged in to a different site is cached, I wouldn't need to provide those credentials. (I completely disagree that this should happen without my permission . . .)

Comment: Oh I see. There is another way to sign up which is to click the sign up button on the top right of the screen. That doesn't involve typing in your Stack ID, but just one more click to confirm that you want to associate your existing account with the new site.